# Single Sign-On with spring session ID cookie?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-session

I'm  working on an project that implements user authentication through Spring Security using a spring session ID stored in a cookie on the client's browser. There's no authentication server, the same server manages authentication and the whole app as a monolith.
So we are now in the need of implementing SSO with a third party system, so far everything I've read on the matter requires OAuth or some other implementation of token based authentication that supports an external identity provider. I would prefer not to migrate the authentication strategy as we are kinda on the clock.
I work on another project that has OAuth authentication so I'm not new on that topic (though not really an expert either).
Can someone throw some light on this? I just need to know if it is possible or there's no other way to migrate the authentication strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie based SSO is only possible (in an easy way) if you are using a so called 'domain cookie'. Technically all applications need to share the same 'cookie domain' then. However from security point of view this is highly discouraged, due to cookie hijacking being possible.

Comment: So this means all applications should be under the same domain?

Comment: Yes, if applications do not share the same cookie domain, the browser won't send the cookie, please see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265.

Example
app1.test.xyz
app.2.abc.test.xyz

Cookie domain 'test.xyz' , browser will send cookie to both apps

app1.a.test.xyz
app2.b.test.xyz

Cookie domain: 'a.test.xyz', browser will send cookie only to 'app1'

Attention: Browsers consider some domains as so called 'public suffix' and for suche domains, domain cookies will be dropped. Please see https://publicsuffix.org/